Cómo hago para copiar un dato de una fila anterior de una columna diferente
El problema que tengo es que al usar el código con datos de tiempo no se comporta igual que cuando uso datos numéricos
Esto era lo que esperaba:

Y esto fue lo que obtuve:

Esto es lo que he intentado con los datos de tiempo:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'BUSES': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'STARTTIME': ['01:00:00', '00:00:00', '02:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00'],
    'DURATION': ['01:30:00', '02:15:00', '00:45:00', '01:12:00', '01:46:00']
}

# Crear DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convertir las columnas de tiempo a objetos de tiempo
df['STARTTIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['STARTTIME'], format='%H:%M:%S')
df['DURATION'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['DURATION'])

# Reemplazar valores nulos o 0 en STARTTIME
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if pd.isnull(df.loc[i, 'STARTTIME']) or df.loc[i, 'STARTTIME'] == pd.to_datetime('00:00:00'):
        if df.loc[i, 'BUSES'] == df.loc[i - 1, 'BUSES']:
            df.loc[i, 'STARTTIME'] = df.loc[i - 1, 'STARTTIME'] + df.loc[i - 1, 'DURATION']

# Calcular la columna SUM
df['SUM'] = df['STARTTIME'] + df['DURATION']

# Formatear las columnas como HH:MM:SS
df['STARTTIME'] = df['STARTTIME'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['DURATION'] = df['DURATION'].dt.total_seconds().apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s').strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
df['SUM'] = df['SUM'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

print(df)

Esto es lo que espero obtener:

Y esto es lo que obtengo:

¿Tienen alguna idea de qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? Les agradezco su ayuda.

El problema es que:
df.loc[i, 'STARTTIME'] == pd.to_datetime('00:00:00')

siempre es False. Esto se debe a que si no especificas el formato, la fecha de salida se infiere/completa a partir de la actual en vez de usar NTP time como base:
>>> pd.to_datetime("00:00:00")
Timestamp('2024-06-01 00:00:00')

>>> pd.to_datetime("00:00:00", format='%H:%M:%S')
Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:00:00')

Al ser las fechas distintas la comparación es siempre falsa:
>>> pd.to_datetime("00:00:00") == pd.to_datetime("00:00:00", format='%H:%M:%S')
False

O normalizas las fechas para que coincidan:
>>> pd.to_datetime("00:00:00", format='%H:%M:%S') == pd.to_datetime("00:00:00", format='%H:%M:%S')
True

o puedes trabajar solo con el componente de tiempo:
>>> pd.to_datetime("00:00:00").time() == pd.to_datetime("00:00:00", format='%H:%M:%S').time()
True

>>> import datetime
>>> pd.to_datetime("00:00:00").time() == datetime.time(0, 0, 0)
True 

Es decir, aunque posiblmente se pueda vectorizar, tu código debería hacer lo que quieres con:
...

# Reemplazar valores nulos o 0 en STARTTIME    
midnight = pd.to_datetime('00:00:00', format='%H:%M:%S')
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if pd.isnull(df.loc[i, 'STARTTIME']) or df.loc[i, 'STARTTIME'] == midnight:

...

Ten en cuenta que "STARTTIME es 0" equivale a medianoche y me resulta extraño considerarlo un valor nulo, no se si realmente esta columna debería ser datetime o si en realidad representa duración (timedelta).

El problema es que los datos de tiempo y duración no se están manejando bien cuando haces la conversión y el cálculo.
Acá te dejo como la corrección amigaso un saludon y cualquier cosa preguntame crack.
(Este cambio en la linea 27.)
df['DURATION'] = df['DURATION'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(' ')[-1])
